# how to prevent a logged in user to edit another using Spring Security Core?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I own the role student in my Spring Security Core. The role student can edit your information. But if he wants to edit another user's information that's also possible.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_STUDENT'])
def edit(Student studentInstance) {
    respond studentInstance
}

@Secured(['ROLE_STUDENT'])
def update(Student studentInstance) {

    if (studentInstance== null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (studentInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond studentInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    studentInstance.save flush:true
    ...
}
```

How to prevent a student logged edit other?

For example, if I type:  http://localhost:8080/app/student/edit/1 - I can edit the information of another user changing only the id

Comment: take a look at Spring Security ACL in docs

Comment: I used as follows, but it did not work:
` 'Secured (['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_STUDENT'])
     PreAuthorize ('IsAuthenticated () and main? .id == # StudentInstance.id')
     def edit (Student studentInstance) {
         Respond studentInstance
     }'`

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Security:s getAuthenticatedUser() to get the currently logged in studentInstance, instead of basing it on an arbitrary supplied params id. Or at least check that the supplied params id matches that of the currently logged in user.